# React Custom Carousel optimization

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an image carousel in react using setInterval and ClearInterval.
And, Iam not sure whether it is a good approach or is there any optimization to do. Help me in optimizing the code or with an alternate solution.

Although for some reason, the Slider Component is called twice causing issue in codesandbox, mentioned the url here. https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-shtern-1wc42?file=/src/Slider.js

```
let currentIndex = 0
let intervalId = false
//If true, add last image to first and first image to last for infinite scrolling
if(infiniteScroll) {
    let firstimg = images[0]
    images.unshift(images[images.length - 1])
    images.push(firstimg)
    currentIndex = 1 //last image is pushed at index 0, so setting currentIndex to 1
}
const slider_ref = ref || React.useRef(null)
const imagesLength = images.length

let autoScrollHandler = () => {
    //AutoScroll always slides in right direction
    arrowHandler('auto')
}
let transitionEndHandler =  () => {
    slider_ref.current.style.transitionProperty = 'none'
    //If true, slide reaches last image, resetting current index to 1
    if(currentIndex + 1 >= imagesLength && infiniteScroll) {
        currentIndex = 1               
    }
    //If true, slide reaches first image, resetting index to last image
    if(currentIndex - 1 <= -1 && infiniteScroll) {
        currentIndex = imagesLength - 2
    }
    if(infiniteScroll) {
        slider_ref.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentIndex * 100}%)`
    }
    else {
        clear()
    }      
}
let arrowHandler = (arrowType) => {
    //If prev decrement index, if auto or next increment index
    currentIndex = arrowType === 'prev' ? currentIndex - 1 : currentIndex + 1
    if(currentIndex < imagesLength && currentIndex > -1) {
        slider_ref.current.style.transitionProperty = 'transform'
        slider_ref.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentIndex * 100}%)`
    }
    //when arrow buttons are clicked need to reset setinterval to stop autoscroll from happening
    if(arrowType !== 'auto' && autoScroll) {
        clear()
        intervalId = setInterval(autoScrollHandler, duration)
    }
}
let clear = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId)
    intervalId = false
}

useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector('.image-slider').addEventListener('transitionend',transitionEndHandler)
    if(autoScroll) {        
        intervalId = setInterval(autoScrollHandler, duration)
    }
    if(pauseOnHover && autoScroll) {
        document.querySelector('.image-slider').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            clear()
        })
        document.querySelector('.image-slider').addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            if(!intervalId) {
                intervalId = setInterval(autoScrollHandler, duration)
            }
        })
    }
    //remove listeners on unmount
    return () => {
        removeEventListener(transitionEndHandler)
        clear()
    }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather go with a library that has been around for a while and is dependable and easy to configure check out React-Slick.
https://react-slick.neostack.com/